# full width absolute positioned footer in ie6

Tags: html, css, sticky-footer

im using a sticky footer, position absolute, but it wont stretch to 100% in IE6. Problem is i need to have different width on its parent container to fake columns. The parent has no width specified but margin-left so to allow anothe bg color for the left column.

```
#footer {
background-color:#ccc;
height:100px;
position:absolute;
bottom:0px;
width:100%;
left:0px;
text-align:center;
}
#wrapper {

background-color:red;
min-height:100%;
height:100%;
margin-left:264px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6hvMC/

Answer (score 0):

It's really hard to believe that in the age of more better browsers you are trying out something for IE6..Also [check this page about MSIE6](http://www.gtalbot.org/BrowserBugsSection/MSIE6Bugs/)

For you problem, you can specify width for the footer in pixels rather than in percentage when the browser is MSIE6..